# How to insert \timing values to tables?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a way how to insert \timing result to table. 
For example, when I execute query, I want to insert executing time result to table.

I tried to write procedure, but it didn't work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_time() 
AS $$
DECLARE
  StartTime timestamptz;
  EndTime timestamptz;
  Delta double precision;
BEGIN
    StartTime := clock_timestamp();
    select count(*) from pracownicy;
    EndTime := clock_timestamp();
    Delta := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
    INSERT INTO czas(id_czas, wynik) VALUES (nextval('czas_sequence'), Delta);
END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
PODPOWIEDŹ:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
KONTEKST:  PL/pgSQL function check_time() line 8 at SQL statement

Comment: So did you follow the advice to use `PERFORM` instead?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) extension instead if you want to track query performance (it also detects same queries with just different constants).

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It was very useful and helpful for my project!